# How to serialize WebClient's response to Mono with generics in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, generics, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

Let's assume I have the following

```
return webClient
                .get()
                .uri { uriBuilder: UriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(myUrl)
                            .queryParam("page", pageable.pageNumber)
                            .queryParam("size", pageable.pageSize)
                            .build()
                }
                .retrieve()
```

I expect to have result like this:

```
PagedResult<MyObject>
```

PagedResult is simple

```
data class PagedResult<T>(
        val content: Iterable<T>,
        val total: Long,
        val page: Int,
        val size: Int)
```

MyObject is trivial POJO as well

I'm trying to do the following:

```
return webClient
                .get()
                .uri { uriBuilder: UriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(poolServiceControllerUrl)
                            .queryParam("page", pageable.pageNumber)
                            .queryParam("size", pageable.pageSize)
                            .build()
                }
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(PagedResult<MyObject>::class.java)
```

It returns me error *only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal*

OK, trying to fix it in this way:

```
val type: Type = object : TypeToken<PagedResult<MyObj>>() {}.type

        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri { uriBuilder: UriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(myUrl)
                            .queryParam("page", pageable.pageNumber)
                            .queryParam("size", pageable.pageSize)
                            .build()
                }
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(type.javaClass)
```

It returns me *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl*

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I ran into it as well.